# Find the cardinality of the set $S_X \ \cap \{f \in X: F(f)=\|F\| \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Define $F:(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $F(f) = \int_{0}^{1} f(t)dt$, $X =\{f \in C[0,1] :f(0)=f(1)=0 \} $ and $S_X =\{f \in X: \|f\|_{\infty} =1 \}$. Then, find the cardinality of the set $S_X \ \cap \{f \in X: F(f)=\|F\| \}$.

**Approach**: clearly $F$ is linear and $|F(f)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$, so we have $\|F\| \leq 1$. and if we take
$$
f (x) = \begin{cases}4x,&{\text{if }}0\leq x\leq 1/2,\\-4(x-1),&{\text{if }} 1/2 \leq x \leq 1.\end{cases}
$$

Then $F (f) =1$. so the question boils down to find the continuous functions on $[0,1]$ whose Maximum is $1$ and which belongs to $X$, such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(t)dt =1 $. After drawing some graphs to gain some intuition, it tells me that there are no such function. But how do we prove this??

Comment: $\|F\|=1$ indeed but you didn't prove it, because the max of your $f$ is $2,$ not $1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $g\in S_X$. Since $g(0)=0$ and $g$ is continuous,  there exists $\delta>0$ such that $g(x)<\frac12$ on $[0,\delta)$. Then, since $g\leq1$,
$$
F(g)=\int_0^\delta g+\int_\delta^1g\leq\frac\delta2+\int_\delta^11=\frac\delta2+1-\delta=1-\frac\delta2<1. 
$$

Note that $g$ is not necessarily non-negative all the way (it may have negative parts) but that does not affect the computations.